# Connected spaces of $M(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Consider $M(n,\mathbb R)$, the space of all  $ n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$.Which of the following are connected?
a.$O(n)$ the set of all orthogonal matrices

b.$GL(n,\mathbb R)$ set of all non-singular matrices over $\mathbb R$

c.$SL(n,\mathbb R)$ set of all non-singular matrices over $\mathbb R$ with determinant equals one.

d.set of all nilpotent matrices.

Answer:since the determinant map is continuous and continuous image of a connected set is connceted using them I have concluded (a),(b) is not connected since image set  of (a) is $\{-1,1\}$and of (b) is $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$. Is  it correct?But how to approach the others

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for (c), you can prove the result by showing that any matrix of $SL_n$ is a product of matrices of the form $I_n+\lambda E_{ij}$ with $i\neq j$, and create a path to the identity by shrinking the $\lambda$ to $0$.

Hint: for (d), if $n$ is nilpotent, then so is $tn$, for $t\in[0,1]$: this is a continuous path of nilpotent matrices that stops at $0$, thus...

Comment: part (d) is ok but (c) I dont get that.I am reading metric spaces.Is there any book that discusses $M(n,\mathbb R)$ in detail@Olivier

Comment: part (c) is elementary matrix manipulations. It is a theorem that these types of matrices generate $SL_n$.

Comment: Ok but how are getting these so easily in fact I have been pondering over it for such a long time .Any suggestion of books

Comment: I learnt all of this in french books... Do you read french?

Comment: No sir, no English books yet

Comment: This is discussed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group#Generators_and_relations, but no details are given unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18310/discussion-between-learnmore-and-olivier-begassat).